# Firebase Realtime Database delete specific user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wish to delete specific user with phone number X from my DB. And insted my code deletes all of them.

Here is my DB:

[image]

Code:

```
    private static void deleteUser(final Context context, final String phoneNumber) {

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        Query usersQuery = databaseReference.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phoneNumber);

        usersQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "Deleted");

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }


        });
    }
```

Comment: You have to loop over the children nodes of the data you have in `dataSnapshot` , using an enhanced for loop like this: `for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { ... }`

Comment: But what if I always have only 1 child with this specific value? Also I need to add "addOnCompleteListener" which start some function. Going through loop it will fire "addOnCompleteListener" for each user. I do not wish it to happen. Surely I said I have max 1 user with this specific phone, but just in case I do not with to create loop.

Comment: Please see my answer @Dim and tell if that explains your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is not clear with my comment, so I am putting this as an answer, the full code that should not be having the problem you're facing, should look something like this:

```java
usersQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                  for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {                
                         ds.getRef().removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                 Log.d(TAG, "Deleted");

                            }
                         });

                  }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }


        });
```

That's because you're using a `singleValueEventListener`. If the query matches multiple children, it returns a list of all those children.

Even if there's only a single matches child, it's still a list of one. And since you're calling `getRef()` on that list, you get the key of the location where you ran the query.

Comment: Ok, but.... Assume is after deleting user I wish to start new activity. So my code inside "onComplete" is startActivity(intent). In case I have 2 users with the same phone number. The function "startActivity(intent)" will be called twise. Am I wrong?

Comment: Read the last lines of my answer, the thing is that when you call `dataSnapshot.getKey()`, if the query matched with multiple children, it gives the list of all those child nodes, but, the interesting thing is that even if it matches only one child node it still returns a list, whose `getKey()` gives you the main parent key that is `users` which then invokes `removeValue()`, and hence deletes the whole list. But when you loop over the child nodes you just get the parent of the child nodes present inside the list of one, so, this gives you the correct reference you need to remove the user.

Comment: Thank you, go it!

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)

Comment: `ds.getKey()` return a String and there is no way you can call `removeValue()` on it. You should use `getRef()` and **not** `getKey()`.